# Show that in a ring R, if a*b=b*a=1 and a*c=1, then b=c

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have begun by showing that R is a commutative ring since the given shows that there exists an inverse of b so that a*b=1 and also that multiplication is commutative. Next I have sown that a is a unit of R by definition because a*b=b*a=1. Also, the units of a ring R form a group under multiplication. So since a*b=b*a=1 and a*c=1 then b and c are inverses of a:

```
a*b=a*c
b*(a*b)=b*(a*c)
(b*a)*b=(b*a)*c by associativity
1*b=1*c since b*a=1
b=c.
```

Does this look like a correct proof?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. More succinctly $\,\ b\, =\, b\,\overbrace{(ac)}^{=\,1}\, =\, \overbrace{(ba)}^{=\, 1}\,c\, =\, c$